# Can I fully statically link a MFC application?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, linker, mfc

I have a simple MFC application built in Visual Studio. I want to be able to link it so any windows PC can run it without needed to install anything else. Just double click the .exe and you are good!

Looking at a debug build, here are my dependencies:

```
VERSION.dll
MSVCP140D.dll
Mfc140d.dll
KERNEL32.dll
USER32.dll
GDI32.dll
SHELL32.dll
OLEAUT32.dll
VCRUNTIME140D.dll
Ucrtgbased.dll
WS2_32.dll
```

I know two of those .dlls are from the Windows Visual C++ Library.

My question is, can I configure my release so that anything this .exe needs is built in? Or will I always need Visual C++ to be installed on the machine that wants to run it. I am guessing that latter, but not sure about the librarys static vs dynamic linking capability.

Comment: Have you tried linking in static libraries?

Comment: A lot of those DLLs are Windows System files.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews not yet. Yeah which I would expect would be no issue. My question is if I need the Visual C++ runtime on EVERY machine this wants to run on

Comment: Please show your project settings.

Comment: Application folder will be checked before searching windows system folder for the dll files, hence copying the required dll files ( 3-4 at most) in the application folder helps avoid collision with other installed libraries.

Comment: @sec [Incorrect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, can I configure my release so that anything this .exe needs is built in? Or will I always need Visual C++ to be installed on the machine that wants to run it?

Yes, you can build the application with static linking, it won’t need the C++ and MFC runtime installed to run.

If you building with the dll dependencies for the C++ runtime and MFC (so not statically linking), you will need to install the VC++ runtime (not the full development environment) on all the machines you distribute to (for servicing this is probably a better option).

You’ll need to read up on the options `/MT`, `/MD` and `/DLL`, specifically to control C++ runtime and MFC linkage, although the IDE makes this much easier to control. Also note, you’ve linked in the debug version (`/MDd` et. al) of the C++ runtime and MFC, you wouldn’t normally distribute it like that. If you need to debug it off the development box, you can still do that by building with symbols and turning off optimisations to get more details on the applications errors.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So to be clear, if the application is MFC, even with statically linking you will still need the runtime on target machines?

Comment: @billybob2 No. if you build static the runtime is not needed. If you do not build static then the runtime in needed. Static build embeds it all in the exe, making it larger.

Comment: @billybob2, no, statically linking means that you are building all the required library code into the target, the application.